# Can't call function inside of jQuery plugin for a facebook login event

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to create a jQuery plugin which will ask for appID and create the facebook login option for the user.

My code is :

```
; (function($){
$.fn.fbLogin = function(options){
    var defaults = {
        appId: ''
    };

    var opt = $.extend(defaults, options);
    var fbRoot = "<div id='fb-root'></div>";
    var fbSdkLoad = "<script async defer crossorigin='anonymous' src='https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.3&appId=" + opt.appId + "&autoLogAppEvents=1'></script>";

    var fbLoginButton = `<div
        class="fb-login-button"
        data-width=""
        data-size="large"
        data-button-type="login_with"
        data-auto-logout-link="false"
        data-use-continue-as="true"
        data-scope="email"
        data-onlogin="loginFB();"
    />`;

    $("body").append(fbRoot);
    $("body").append(fbSdkLoad);
    $("body").append(fbLoginButton);

    function loginFB(){
        console.log("yes");
    }
}
})(jQuery);
```

when I load this plugin in my index.html file then Login with Facebook button is loaded. When I click it, a popup appears and then I got the following error in my dev console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: loginFB is not defined
```

When I add the loginFB function in index.html in a script, it works, which makes sense as login button is there in body scope, and can call the function.

But I want to have a function which will do some work after login which needs to be stayed inside the plugin function.

Can anyone suggest me any better approach for this ?

Comment: You've defined the `loginFB()` function within the scope of the plugin handle handler. Move it to a global scope. It needs to be there as the Facebook SDK calls the function from an `onclick` attribute

Comment: Hey @RoryMcCrossan, thanks for your answer, I have added that in my question."When I add the loginFB function in index.html in a script, it works, which makes sense as login button is there in body scope, and can call the function."

 I want to keep the function inside the plugin. Is there any way for that ?

Comment: No. Facebook uses `on` event attributes in HTML, so the functions it calls need to be global. Ugly, and backwards, but hey, that's Facebook for you.